# Scala: packages cannot be represented as URI

Tags: scala, installation

I have openjdk, scala and sbt, all installed via brew. I'm trying to 
get setup to work on the scala track on exercism. I'm having no 
troubles with Java or anything that uses the JVM like clojure, but
when I try to test my installation of scala by running the test for
the exercism hello example:

```
$ sbt test
```

I get a bunch of errors that seem to start with this:

java.io.IOError: java.lang.RuntimeException: 
/packages cannot be represented as URI

My installed versions are as follows:

```
$ java --version
openjdk 13.0.1 2019-10-15
OpenJDK Runtime Environment AdoptOpenJDK (build 13.0.1+9)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM AdoptOpenJDK (build 13.0.1+9, mixed mode, sharing)

$ scala -version
Scala code runner version 2.13.1 -- 

$ sbt --version
sbt version in this project: 1.3.8
sbt script version: 1.3.8
```

I've looked and seen this error in a few questions but not seen a way to fix it.

Comment: Can you share some code to reproduce the problem?

Comment: The problem is not with the code, it's with the tooling.  The code is from https://exercism.io/my/tracks/scala, the hello project. The code compiles, it's a java runtime error.

Comment: given `sbt test` I supposed a project, I do not know what does it mean to run it outside of any project, but I guess it shouldn't throw that exception. Does the same happens if you run the **repl** with the `scala` command? If so, I would guess the problem is your JDK version, but according to [this](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/jdk-compatibility/overview.html#jdk-13-and-14-compatibility-notes) it should just work.

Comment: Related issue: https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/5093. It's a long thread, the first things to check would be if you're specifying different Scala and/or SBT version in build.sbt or project/build.properties?

Comment: Exercism is providing a project.sbt with an older version of scala listed. I fixed this and no longer get -that- error. So this is fixed.

Comment: Any update on this? Faced some issue, it really depends on environment

Comment: I also fixed this problem by editing the build.sbt file

Comment: I had the same issue with using mill and Scala 2.12.4. Just upgrading Scala to 2.13.1 fixed it. I'm using openjdk 14 2020-03-17

Comment: Not sure how or why, but upgrading sbt to 1.4.5 fixed this error for me on Java 15.

Answer (score 61):

I solved the issue by installing a java version of 1.8 and set JAVA_HOME towards this version.

`export JAVA_HOME="/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_251.jdk/Contents/Home"`

Comment: Must have skipped this step during a recent machine set up. Thank you so much. Saved me great headache.

Comment: This worked for me as well.

Answer (score 11):

I've got the same issue on IntelliJ IDEA and solved it with

Settings > Build, Exec... > Build Tools > sbt > JRE > set to 1.8.

`JAVA_HOME` has not resolve it in my case

Answer (score 5):

In my case, in Intellij IDEA, I had `JAVA_HOME` as well as sbt JRE from the previous answer set to 1.8, but I completely forgot about the Project SDK, which was set to an incompatible version.

`Ctrl + Alt + Shift + S > Project Settings > Project > Project SDK`

Setting this to 1.8 as well as language levels of modules to 8 fixed my issues.

Answer (score 4):

Intellij :

open `Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Scala Compiler -> Scala Compile Server`, then change the JDK to the one your project used. This solution solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

I found [this S/O answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73437091/18645362) solves my issue:

> This is a Scala compiler bug. Please upgrade to the latest Scala point release, 2.12.16.

Answer (score 1):

What helped me here was:

File > Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > Compiler > Scala Compile Server

Beside JDK, I set it to 1.8, built the application, issue was resolved.

Answer (score 0):

IntelliJ:

- Go to `File -> Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Build Tools -> sbt`
- Make sure `Use sbt shell for build` is checked

Answer (score 0):

Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Scala Compiler -> Scala Compile Server work for me

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it is related to Intellij's Scala compile server settings.

go to settings -> Build, Exec... -> Compiler -> Scala Compile Server

uncheck **use compile server**

this solved the issue for me